# I need to run a loop that will take the cells value and store it on another if there is anything there and then check the next line

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I have code so far which I have posted below, but as you can see it's very insufficient way to do it and isn't running a loop and wont help me if I end having more than items that are below A22. What the code here is doing is when I press a button it will read through each sheet on the workbook and if cell A5 has "Project # :" then it will see if cell A19 has anything if it does it will take whats in cell A19,C19,E19,F19 and G19 and put it on my worksheet named "Data Sheet". The current code has it so it does that process through A22 but I want it to be automated with a loop so that it checks the cell A5 for "Project # :" and if it finds that then it checks if A19 is blank, if it is end the loop. If it has any sort of text then I want it to take the values from Column A,C,E,F and G and putting it onto the "Data Sheet" . Then it will loop to the next now (row 20) and repeat the process it did for the previous one.
Currently my code is correctly working to get the data to the right spot but my IF-ELSE for rows 19-22 is just inefficient and not sure how to code the loop.

```
Sub NonStoresItems()

With Worksheets("Data Sheet")
    ' Clear previous data on the All projects page
    .Rows("141:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A5") = "Project # :" Then


            If Range("A19") = "" Then

            Else:
                x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
                .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
                .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$19"    'Non-stores material
                .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$C$19"    'Lead Time
                .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$19"    'Order By Date
                .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$19"    'Date Ordered
                .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$19"    'Goals Met
          End If


          If Range("A20") = "" Then

          Else:
            x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
            .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
            .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$20"    'Non-stores material
            .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$C$20"    'Lead Time
            .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$20"    'Order By Date
            .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$20"    'Date Ordered
            .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$20"    'Goals Met
          End If


          If Range("A21") = "" Then

          Else:
            x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
            .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
            .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$21"    'Non-stores material
            .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$C$21"    'Lead Time
            .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$21"    'Order By Date
            .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$21"    'Date Ordered
            .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$21"    'Goals Met
          End If


          If Range("A22") = "" Then

          Else:
            x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
            .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
            .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$22"    'Non-stores material
            .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$C$22"    'Lead Time
            .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$22"    'Order By Date
            .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$22"    'Date Ordered
            .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$22"    'Goals Met
          End If


        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

[Data Sheet Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAXKf.png)
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVWdJ.png)

Comment: Why don't you just copy/cut and paste the values?

Comment: This is a project tracking work sheet and projects can be added at any point and these specific rows can change throughout the project so I want it to be Automated to do so because there can be over 100 hundred projects.

Comment: I get how you want it automated, but you can automate copying and pasting, as opposed to assigning each individual cell a reference value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in place of your `If...Else` statements

```
z = 19

Do While Not Range("A" & z) = ""
    x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
    .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
    .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$" & z    'Non-stores material
    .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$C$" & z    'Lead Time
    .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$" & z    'Order By Date
    .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$" & z    'Date Ordered
    .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$" & z    'Goals Met
    z = z + 1
Loop
```

This will loop until it finds and empty value in column A, if you want to stop at 22 every time just add `AND z < 23` to the `Do While` condition.

Comment: I tried using this block of code and get an error on the "Dim z = 19" I keep getting an error box that says "Compile Error: Expected: End of Statement"

Comment: Sorry, add `Dim z As Integer` at the top of your sub where you declare your variables, then just use `z = 19`, or for short hand you can just use `z = 19`

Comment: For some reason, when I run it, it puts 0 on a bunch of cells when there clearly nothing in those cells. check my original post, I added the pictures showing this

Comment: Is it putting a zero, or is it putting a formula in those cells?  If the latter then it's running past where it needs to.  If that's the case, try adding `AND Not IsNull(Range("A" & z))`

Comment: it is putting a 0 and when you press and look at formula bar it is putting ='1'!$A$22       1 is the sheets name

Comment: Not sure why it's not stopping, but the formula that it's inserting is the proper one according to your code, did you try to add the `Not IsNull(Range("A" & z))`

Comment: Yes I did and the Do While now says: Do While Not Range("A" & Z) = "" And Not IsNull(Range("A" & Z))

Comment: In place of `IsNull` try `IsEmpty`

Comment: It is still doing the same thing

Comment: Not sure if it'll make a difference, but force it to make sure it's checking the current worksheet by changing `Range("A" & z)` to `ws.Range("A" & z)`